Are somanassa and cetasik-sukha same thing?
Some teacher (Goenka) says vedanānupassanā is bodily only because sukha and dukha in general are bodily.
But the definition of sukha includes cetasikaṃ vā sukhaṃ too

Yaṃ kho, āvuso visākha, kāyikaṃ vā cetasikaṃ vā sukhaṃ sātaṃ vedayitaṃ: ayaṃ sukhā vedanā.
(Cūḷavedalla sutta)

So my question is, how a cetasikaṃ sukhaṃ different from somanassa?

somanassa includes both cetasikaṃ sukhaṃ, and
cetasikaṃ sātaṃ,
https://lucid24.org/sn/main/sn48/index.html#48.37
SN 48.37.3 – (so-manssa indriya = mental happiness)

“katamañca, bhikkhave, so-manass-indriyaṃ?
“what, ************, (is the) good-mental-[state]-faculty?
yaṃ kho, bhikkhave,
Whatever ***, ************,
cetasikaṃ sukhaṃ,
mental pleasure,
cetasikaṃ sātaṃ,
mental satisfaction,
mano-samphassajaṃ sukhaṃ sātaṃ vedayitaṃ —
mind-contact-produced pleasurable satisfying feeling –
idaṃ vuccati, bhikkhave, so-manass-indriyaṃ.
that (is) called, *********, good-mental-[state]-faculty.


As per MN 137 wher 18   mental upvicara are given. it clearly says somanasa are related to viptaka/vicara . hence  grocer then sukhas.

moreover defination of 4th Jhana also gives same pointer : Sukhassa ca pahānā dukkhassa ca pahānā pubbeva somanassadomanassānaṃ atthaṅgamā

probably somanass-indriyam is one thing and somanassa is different thing.


probably somanass-indriyam is one thing and somanassa is different thing . possible, but  I doubt it. they're both going to be mental pleasant state though. sukha is different than sukha indriya because sukha unqualified can refer to sukha vedana which is different than sukha indriya

